# Return on first result with Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to generate a set of random values that fulfill certain requirements.

I'd like to do this in parallel to try and speed it up. That is, something like this:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
pool.map(gen_random_set, [set_size]*8)
```

However, I don't need multiple sets, just one. How do I terminate the pool (presumably using `pool.terminate()`) after the very first set is found?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of terminating :

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
    def worker(i):
     time.sleep(3)
     print(i)

    mypool = Pool()
    a = mypool.map_async(worker,range(1000))
```

when you run this , your pool execution will stop:

```
multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate(mypool)
```

the name 'mypool' should be same as the pool object you created by mypool=Pool()